# How to reorder folders? (as displayed in `ls -U`)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sorting

I've got a number of unordered folders on a memory stick, which my car stereo shows in order of their real position on the stick (i.e. same as `ls -U`) What's the easiest way of physically reordering these directories? (moving all directories to a 'tmp' folder and back seems to work via GUI, but not particularly elegant...)

#### UPDATE: re. FATSORT

`fatsort` (see answer below) seems to do the job nicely.
The order of actions is now:
**1.** `sudo umount /media/USB_STICK_NAME`
**2.** `sudo blkid` (which tells me the device: `/dev/sdc1: LABEL="USB_STICK_NAME" ...`)
**3.** `sudo fatsort /dev/sdc1`

Comment: if your memory stick was ext<2,3>, i'd say run `fsck.ext<2,3> -D` on it. as that would compact and sort the directories. but as it most likely fat32, i don't have a clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at this link:

http://www.murraymoffatt.com/software-problem-0010.html

According to what I am reading there is a utility called [FATSort](http://fatsort.sourceforge.net/) which can re-arrange the files for you.

It is actually also available from the Ubuntu repositories so:

```
sudo apt-get install fatsort
```

Answer (score 0):

For a tool that integrates fatsort and provides features on top of it:

[plgen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plgen/)