# How to physically reorder files `03.mp3   01.mp3   02.mp3` (`ls -f`) in a directory?

Tags: linux, find, ls

The **physical order** of the files matters when I copy them onto my USB stick and listen in car mp3 player. Most of my music album folders are **unsorted**, e.g. **`ls -f`** may produce:
03.song3.mp3
01.song1.mp3
02.song2.mp3

When I copy that folder onto my USB stick, the files get copied in **that** order. My car mp3 player displays the files in the unsorted order, which is not what I want.
I can subsequently reorder the files on the USB stick (see: [How to reorder folders? (as displayed in `ls -U`)](https://superuser.com/questions/368623/how-to-reorder-folders-as-displayed-in-ls-u)), but could avoid that altogether if I could **reorder them within that directory** them on my hard drive (ext4)? Is there a way of doing that?

(Failing that, there might be a way of writing a **`find`** command, that gets the files, sorts them, and then copies them in order??) Any suggestions?

Comment: Alternatively, you could sort the files *after* copying them onto the mp3 player: http://superuser.com/questions/368623/how-to-reorder-folders-as-displayed-in-ls-u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unlikely that you'll be able to do this on ext4. Unlike FAT(32), which used a linear table of files in a directory, modern filesystems use complex structures such as B+tree (NTFS, XFS) or [hashed B-tree](http://ext2.sourceforge.net/2005-ols/paper-html/node3.html) (ext3/4), where all entries are sorted according to a specific algorithm.

In particular, ext3/4 sorts files according to the hash value of their name, so you *always* get the same files in the same order. It's possible to disable the *dir_index* feature via `tune2fs`, but it might cost you performance if you have directories containing many files.

---

A very basic command for this could be `cp dir/* otherdir/`, where the shell sorts names when expanding arguments, and `cp` simply copies them in the order given.

Something more complex, for copying subdirectories:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
srcdir=$1
destdir=$2

find "$srcdir" \( -type d -printf "0dir %P\0" \) \
            -o \( -type f -printf "1file %P\0" \) |
sort -z | while read -r -d '' type path; do
    case $type in
        "0dir") mkdir -vp "$destdir/$path";;
        "1file") cp -v "$srcdir/$path" "$destdir/$path";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to e.g. `move` the files to say a `new_tmp` folder, and then moving them back but dictate the order? (Seems to work from within a GUI for the folders?!)

Comment: @ajo: If the filesystem has dir_index enabled, it won't work. Regardless of which order you move/create files in, they will have the same sort order as long as they have the same name. Try, for example, `mkdir test1 test2; touch test1/{a,b,c,d} test2/{d,c,b,a}; ls -f test1 test2` -- the files will be sorted in the same order (`a c b .. d .` in my system) even though they were created in reverse.

Comment: the `cp dir/* otherdir/` looks a lot easier, but uses the original order. could I implement sorting there?

Comment: @ajo: The *shell* is supposed to sort file names before launching `cp`. Try `echo dir/*` to see what they expand to. But again, it only matters when copying to FAT memory sticks; it will *not* change anything when copying to ext4.

Comment: does this look OK for single directory? `find SRC_DIR -iname '*mp3' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 -I {} cp {} DEST_DIR`

Comment: Yes, it should work. You can always test with `xargs -0 echo`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like others have similar [problems](http://yhoo.it/ZQn2K2).

[Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plgen/) that lets users arrange files according to their wishes and sorts the FAT file system low-level style.

[Same tool](http://freecode.com/projects/plgen) on freecode.com

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some options

- [fatsort](https://fatsort.sourceforge.io) (macOS command line, careful)
- [DriveSort](http://www.anerty.net/software/file/DriveSort/?lang=en) (Windows, easy)